# atom_concat works on swi-prolog but not gprolog

Tags: prolog

I'm having this simple code :

```
A is 1, atom_concat(A,'1', L).
```

SWI-prolog gives me :

```
A = 1,
L = '11'.
```

as intended but on gprolog I have :

```
uncaught exception: error(type_error(atom,1),atom_concat/3)
```

Why is there a difference of output between swi-prolog and gprolog ? Which one is right ?

Thanks

Comment: `1` is not an atom but an **integer**.

Comment: THe problem comes from the A not the 1 since `atom_concat(1,1,L)` does work.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with `string_concat("abc","def",Result).`. I'm getting crazy over this !

Comment: How can you be having exactly the same problem with `string_concat/3`? It isn't an ISO predicate and isn't part of GNU Prolog. So GNU tells you it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Kenshin `atom_concat(1, 1, L)` does not work in GNU Prolog. The difference you're seeing has nothing to do with the `A`. SWI Prolog happens to internally convert the number `1` to an atom `'1'` before doing the concatenation. In fact, `atom_concat(1, '1', L)` in SWI will yield `L = '11'`. But technically it's going above and beyond the call of duty for valid `atom_concat/3` behavior. In GNU Prolog, you can do, `number_atom(N, A), atom_concat(A, '1', R)` if `N` is a number.

Comment: Thank you so much ! It works perfectly. I tried with `number_atom(A, N)`but of course I had an error.

Comment: Please note that SWI is here erroneuous which simply sets wrong expectations. `atom_concat/3` is defined over atoms **only**. It's like that in the standard, and virtually all related systems. GNU is completely right to produce an error. In SWI, you get all kinds of odd behavior due to this non-conforming extension, like `X = 1, atom_concat(X,X,11)` succeeds, but `atom_concat(X,X,11), X = 1` fails. This has ots of consequences that make programs less reliable. So at the first glance you might get the impression that this is useful, you are paying for it dearly losing consistency and stability.

Comment: Thanks, this is much clearer now !

Comment: @Kenshin It always pays to check the documentation. ;) Also, `number_atom/2` is very intentionally named as to indicate that the "number" comes first, then the "atom" in the argument list. ;)

Comment: I thought that prolog was the almost the same between gprolog and swi prolog. I used `atom_number/2` from http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atom_number/2 ! Now I know :)

Comment: `atom_number/2` accepts an atom as the first argument and number as the second, as indicated in the name. :) There are a lot of differences between GNU and SWI Prologs although both do have a lot of support for ISO predicates. When choosing predicates, and you're concerned about portability, you might want to check whether the predicate is ISO.